How does my book get this polynomial fraction result?
I'm currently reading through my Real Analysis textbook on functions. At one point in examples for the limits of functions they have:$\frac{|5x^3 - 4x^2 - 24|}{5(x^2+1)}$ = $\frac{|5x^3+6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)}\times|x-2|$
I know this is simple algebra and am embarrassed for not knowing it, but how did they get that?

You must copy it wrong as the degrees of the numerators don't equal.

Typo, the factored version must be  $5x^2+6x+12$   Please do the multiplication $(x-2) (   5x^2+6x+12 )$  and see if it is a correct factoring

Thank you, I was banging my head on how the heck the factoring was right, it is indeed a typo. Thank you Will Jagy
